# how to combine 2 arrays into one associative array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, merge, associative-array

i need to combine `ARRAY1` and `ARRAY2` into an associative array like `ARRAY`. i'm using this code:

```
 mapfile -t ARRAY1 < <(/bin/awk '{ print $ 1 }' /output/gen_branch)
 mapfile -t ARRAY2 < <(/bin/awk '{ print $ 6 }' /output/gen_code )
 declare -A ARRAY

 for ((i=0; $i<${#ARRAY1[@]}; i++))
 do
 ARRAY+=( ["${ARRAY1[i]}"] = "${ARRAY2[i]}" )
 done

 ##added this loop to check output
 for value in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
 do
 echo "branch: $value"
 echo "code: ${ARRAY[$value]}"
 done
```

i expect something like this to use them in other parts of bash (it is important that the value of **first** element of `ARRAY1` be the **first** element of `ARRAY2` and so on) :

```
ARRAY1=( b1 b2 b3 )
ARRAY2=( c1 c2 c3 )
ARRAY= ( [b1]=c1 [b2]=c2 [b3]=c3 )
```

but when i run my code i get this error:

```
line 7: ARRAY: [b1]: must use subscript when assigning associative array
line 7: ARRAY: =: must use subscript when assigning associative array
line 7: ARRAY: c1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
(and it goes on like this for every entry)
```

i think i'm doing it all wrong on line 7.what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Remove spaces around `=`

Comment: @muru it worked. would you like to turn it into an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Why not do the whole thing in `awk`?

Comment: Also note the `$ 1` and `$ 6` in the `awk` code (the spaces after `$` should probably not be there).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas which part?

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for mentioning that. it is because of application. in every `awk` i should write that space

Comment: @Kusalananda, `$` is an operator like any other in `awk`, there's no problem having spaces around it, not any more than around `+` or `*`.

Comment: `awk` is a tool designed for text processing and with associative array support and is much more efficient at it than a shell. So, unless you need to run some commands on the elements of that associative array (a shell is the tool to run other commands, `awk` does invoke a shell to run other commands for instance), it would make more sense to use `awk`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm aware. I opposed the space on grounds of readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must not be spaces around the `=`.

Using

```
hash[${array1[i]}]=${array2[i]}
```

would be more legible IMO.

For the record, in `zsh`, to turn two arrays into an associative array/hash, you'd do:

```
typeset -A hash
hash=("${(@)array1:^array2}")
```

Where `${array1:^array2}` is the *array zipping* operator and the `@` parameter expansion flag is used to preserve empty elements (in double quotes, similar to `"$@"`). (by the way, bash hashes don't support empty keys).

Comment: Note that ordering of keys is not guaranteed by eg bash